# Javascript method is not a function

Tags: javascript

```
function makeGroup(param) {
  this.group = param;
}

duplicateEmployee.makeGroup(index2);
```

Doing a simple duplicateEmployee.group = index2 doesn't work. Trying a method says "makeGroup is not a function."

Here's the full code for reference.

```
var someVar = [];
vm.contacts = ContactsService.query(employees => {
  employees.forEach(employee => {
    employee.groups.forEach((groupMembership, index2) => {
      // getEmployee() works...
      function getEmployee(param) {
        return param;
      }

      // "makeGroup is not a function"
      function makeGroup(param) {
        this.group = param;
      }

      var duplicateEmployee = getEmployee(employee);
      if (groupMembership) {
        duplicateEmployee.makeGroup(index2); // this breaks it. Says makeGroup is not a function
        console.log(groupMembership, index2); // index2 is working... that's the group number
        someVar.push(duplicateEmployee);
      }
    });
  });
});
vm.contacts = someVar;
```

Tried this and it doesn't work

```
      function makeGroup(param1, param2) { // console.log(param2) === undefined
        console.log(param1); // group number... not the employee (still useful)
        console.log(this); // 'this' is the employee, so lets try this.group
        this.group = param1; // still overwriting the variable
      }

      makeGroup.call(duplicateEmployee, index2)
```

Comment: `duplicateEmployee` is just a variable that has whichever value `param` has, it doesn't have a function called `makeGroup`

Comment: That is because your employee object has no makeGroup function.

Comment: so instead of function makeGroup it should be function duplicateEmployee.makeGroup (param) {}?

Comment: @TravisJ that's why I'm confused with methods. Normally functions just work, and I'm not sure the difference.

Comment: No, for that to work you'd have to make an `Employee` kind of class, add `makeGroup` to it's prototype, create a new class in your code, and then call that function. Also I don't get the point of creating those two functions only available in your `forEach` scope.

Comment: function duplicateEmployee.makeGroup(param) { doesn't work ("unexpected .")

Comment: Am I on the right path? If I update the variable directly, it overwrites the previous changes. So I get three people (what I want) all in group 3 instead of 1 person in group 1, 1 person in group 2, 1 person in group 3. console.log(index2) gives the right groups, though (1, 2, 3)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling a method `makeGroup` of a `duplicateEmployee` object. This object does not have this method in it. You can either add it to its `prototype` or just change `makeGroup` so that it's a function that takes in the employee and the param, and it'd be something like so.

```
function makeGroup(employee, param) {
  employee.group = param;
}
```

The reason `getEmployee` works is because you're calling it from the global context, and not from a `duplicateEmployee` context like you're doing with `makeGroup`.

Comment: Thank you. employee.group keeps getting overwritten when I try this. It would be the same as saying duplicateEmployee.group = index2

Comment: That's because your `duplicateEmployee` isn't actually getting a copy of the employee you want, it's getting a reference to it. So whenever you change `duplicateEmployee` you're also changing `employee`. Can you tell me if the problem is fixed if you do `return Object.assign({}, param)` instead of `return param` in `getEmployee`?

Answer (score 1):

`duplicateEmployee.makeGroup(index2);` can't be called from the employee because it's not a member of that.
You can just call it like that `makeGroup(index2)`

Comment: I have my doubts if this is going to work once inside makeGroup it is using "this". Maybe he could pass an employee as a parameter or invoke through `makeGroup.call(duplicateEmployee, index2)`

Comment: So should I create a whole new method to construct the employee for this one? Something like this https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_create_object3

Comment: @dime2lo "CreateListFromArrayLike called on non-object" when I try makeGroup.apply(duplicateEmployee, index2) and function makeGroup(param1, param2) {
            param1.group = param;
          }

Comment: @TylerL I edited the response (sorry). It must be called with `call` not `apply`, using   `apply` have to pass parameters as array. It should be `makeGroup.call(duplicateEmployee, index2)`. Regards.

Comment: I think we're getting there. I'll modify the original question with your suggested update.

Comment: I think we're getting there. I'll modify the original question with your suggested update. Edit: Fix is in dogui's comments. Still a mystery as to how this code would have worked with the makeGroup function/method/...whatever. Thank you for your support :)